# Title Format - Auto Generation via linked entry

Tags: entry, titles

Finally hopping back into Craft to finish a large project, and am loving so many of the new features added! One thing I am using extensively is the Title Format feature. For one of my entry types, my Title Format field looks like so:

```
{songTitle} - {{ performedWith.entry.title }}
```

performedWith is the name of a field that links to an entry. I assumed I could do entry.title to pull the title from the linked entry, but it is simply showing up blank. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Lindsey's answer is correct when outputting to a template, however, from within the title field of an Entry Type you would use the following:

```
{songTitle} - {performedWith.first.title}
```

`entry` is not needed, and only need single brackets.

Comment: Ahhh, "title format"... somehow I completely missed that!

Answer (score 1):

If `performedWith` is a simple relationship field to another entry, then try it like this:

```
{{ entry.performedWith.first.title }}
```

Then you're getting the `title` from the `first` entry listed in your `performedWith` field.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is indeed a simple relationship field, but even when using the first parameter, it is coming back blank. So it looks like:

{songTitle} -

The artist name *should* be listed after the -.

Comment: Oops, caught a typo... Updated my answer, try that.

Comment: Still no dice. :(

Comment: Couple questions... Are you on a normal `entry` page? And do you have the site running in [`devMode`](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/dev-mode)? If the site is running in `devMode`, you can use [`{{ dump() }}`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) to find out what your variables contain.

Comment: Using `dump`, you should be able to determine that (1) `entry` is an EntryModel, (2) `entry.performedWith` is an ElementCriteriaModel, (3) `entry.performedWith.first` is another EntryModel, and (4) `entry.performedWith.first.title` is a string... specifically, the string which you are trying to display. If for some reason that's not the architecture of those fields (or if some other error is popping up), then simply being in `devMode` should shed a little light on the problem.

Comment: Finding this one a bit more difficult to debug, as the code is in the Title field itself of the section, not in a template. Guess this one is something I will come back to as I get a bit further with the rest of the site. Will be sure to post back when I figure it out.

Comment: try `{songTitle} - {performedWith.first.title}`

Comment: My bad, I led you in the wrong direction... Somehow I completely missed the fact that your question was asking about the Title Format. Thanks @DouglasMcDonald for [setting me straight](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/5441/45)! :)